# Defining new custom projections in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I'm trying to define a projection in [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/). I want to add [North America Albers Equal Area Conic](http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/102008/). From the [spatialreference](http://spatialreference.org/) site I copied the `proj4` line:

`+proj=aea +lat_1=20 +lat_2=60 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs`

Then I went into `QGIS -> Settings -> Custom CRS` and pasted the following into the window:

[image]

But when I go to view the projection within QGIS I see a very different set of parameters:

[image]

Is this ok?

I don't know enough about projections to tell if the parameters generated are the correct ones, or whether something else is going on. It also ignored the name that I provided which made me suspect the parameters may also be incorrect.

I'm using QGIS 1.7.3 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

@underdark made me realize that I didn't actually press `save` while defining the CRS. So, what I needed to do was first click `save`, and then to click `ok`. The projection then showed up fine.

[image]

Comment: With QGIS Master 1.9.0, the issue is solved. No need for a bug report anymore...