# How to add FP_WGS_84_IBCAO_Polar_Stereographic projection to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff

I have a GeoTIFF image that is projected (see below), I would like to add this projection to the list of CRS in QGIS.

Can someone help me do this?

```
PROJCS["FP_WGS_84_IBCAO_Polar_Stereographic",
   GEOGCS["FG_WGS_84",
      DATUM["FD_WGS_1984",
         SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
      PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
      UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
   UNIT["meter",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
   PROJECTION["Polar_Stereographic"],
   PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",75],
   PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
   PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
   PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
   PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
   AUTHORITY["EPSG","3996"],
   AXIS["X",
      UNKNOWN],
   AXIS["Y",
      UNKNOWN]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly the only reference to this projection that Google can find is this question. However if you go to http://spatialreference.org/ref/?search=polar&srtext=Search you'll find a list of similar projections.

You can then pick one which has a similar Human readable WKT (e.g. http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3031/html/) and then go to the Proj.4 link (http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3031/proj4/) then copy this text into QGis and modify the number that are different in the WKT and your WKT above.

[How to define new custom projections in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20566/how-to-define-new-custom-projections-in-qgis) discusses how to add the projection to QGis.