# How to add EPSG:5235 to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, georeferencing, epsg

First of all I should say I am new to EPSG and QGIS world.Then 
I want to Georeferced Raster image to EPSG:5235 in QGIS. But in Qgis I can't found above EPSG. How I add this EPSG to Qgis ?

Pls help me,

Thanks

Comment: if you know the parameters, you can define it as a Custom CRS. Settings -> Custom CRS. I couldn't find 5235 in the EPSG database. What are you trying to use it for?

Comment: for defining new projection u can check out this question [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/20566/3071) which had asked before... i hope it helps you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what, SLD99/Sri Lanka Grid 1999? As mentioned, you'll have to define a custom CRS for this. The parameters I have are as follows:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=7.000471527777778 +lon_0=80.77171308333334 +k=0.9999238418 +x_0=500000 +y_0=500000 +a=6377276.345 +b=6356075.41314024 +towgs84=-0.293,766.95,87.713,0.195704,1.69507,3.47302,-0.039338 +units=m +no_defs
```

But I have nothing with which to test this I'm afraid.

Nick.