# Custom Geographic Transformation on QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

Is there a way to create a custom geographic transformation with specifics parameters in QGIS like in ArcGIS?

Okay, I want to tranform SAD69 system into WGS84. Well, I'm in doubt because in ArcGIS you have to enter both systems and then specify the method of the transformation - wich is the Molodensky method - and its three parameters - defined by the brazilian government.

```
a1 = 6.378.160 m
f1 = 1/298,25
a2 = 6.378.137 m
f2 = 1/298,257222101 ΔX = − 67,35 m
ΔY = + 3,88 m
ΔZ = − 38,22 m
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's possible to create custom coordinate reference systems (CRSs) in QGIS. Settings -> Custom CRS...

What parameters do you have?

Added later: Is this SAD69 lat/lon? You could try a custom CRS made with this parameter string:

```
+proj=longlat +ellps=aust_SA +towgs84=-67.35,3.88,-38.22,0,0,0,0 +no_defs
```

See here [How to define new custom projections in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20566/how-to-define-new-custom-projections-in-qgis)

Comment: Okay, I want to tranform SAD69 system into WGS84. Well, I'm in doubt because in ArcGIS you have to enter both systems and then specify the method of the transformation - wich is the Molodensky method - and its three parameters - defined by the brazilian government.                               a1 = 6.378.160 m
f1 = 1/298,25
a2 = 6.378.137 m
f2 = 1/298,257222101 ΔX = − 67,35 m
ΔY = + 3,88 m
ΔZ = − 38,22 m

Comment: I've added a suggestion to my answer above. Nick.

Comment: No, actually SAD69 is projected (X/Y)!

Comment: Some are geographic and some are projected. See http://spatialreference.org/ref/?search=SAD69

Comment: Could you please explain how I enter the parameter string in the CRS window?