# Automatically creating user CRS from postgis in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, coordinate-system, postgresql

I have my custom CRS in table "spatial_ref_sys" in database. When I load layer from schema "public", QGIS create this CRS. But if layer from other schema, it's not. What I need to solve this problem?

Comment: do you have another spatial_ref_sys table under you "other schema" ? do you have any specific  Privileges on the public schema's table ?

Comment: I try to create view of spatial_ref_sys table in other schema, but it doesn't work. 
What specific privilegies did you say about?

Comment: because  you can revoke  privilege to read public schema but by default it's allow, so if you didnot create specific privilege on public schema, it's may not a privilege error.

Comment: did you remove the spatial_ref_sys you create on the "other schema" ? how do you create the "other schema" ?  on the postgis doc  5.8.3. The Schema Search Path [link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html) you can read that *The system determines which table is meant by following a search path, which is a list of schemas to look in. The first matching table in the search path is taken to be the one wanted.* So, if you don't have a table "spatial_ref_sys" on you "other schema" QGIS should get the spatial ref entry from the public.spatial_ref_sys table.

Comment: @HugoRoussaffa-GeoDatup I didn't create specific privilege, but anyway I'm log in as superuser. 
Also I tried to move "spatial_ref_sys" and extension "postgis" on "other schema". QGIS defines srid of CRS from database in postgis dialog window , but when I add a layer, it without any CRS.

Comment: can you give us the output  of those command : `\d yourTable` and also this one `SELECT * from spatial_ref_sys WHERE spatial_ref_sys.srid = Find_SRID('OtherShema', 'yourTable', 'GeometryColum');` ?

Comment: @HugoRoussaffa-GeoDatup 
1. What informantion do you need from this query? It's just a structure of table, isn't it?
2. This command execution is succefull. I got a string with CRS, which I add in "spatial_ref_sys" table and assignied this table

Comment: Just want to be sure that your table and Spatial_ref_sys are greatly construct. But, nevertheless, I decided to try on my own, and  QGIS does not *create the custom CRS* (as the table is under public schema or not). So, can you give us more detail on how you did that ? you can see this [old answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/32008/53945) that you need to recreate the CRS under QGIS. I don"t know how QGIS define the matching between the custom CRS in QGIS and the Custom SRID in postgis... it's a question to ask !

Comment: @HugoRoussaffa-GeoDatup Hm, I didn't define any specific parametres. QGIS did it himself. If I find causes, I will write you. Thank you!