# Automated matching between the QGIS custom CRS and a custom SRID from Postgis

Tags: qgis, postgis, coordinate-system

According to this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/32008/53945) we know that QGIS does not get the SRS from the postgis spatial_ref_sys table. We have to define the custom SRID under QGIS.

Is there a way that QGIS can make the matching automatically between his custom CRS in QGIS and the Custom SRID in postgis?

Comment: Can you specify how you would like to make the automatic match? By pyqgis?

Comment: I am looking for the simplest way as possible. I create a Custom CRS in QGIS and the same in postgis but I don't know how to make the CRS matching when I load the table from UI. QGis Custom CRS don't have EPSG, so QGIS might not recognizing the postgis SRID, isn't it ? If you have a PyQGis solution let us know how you think it could be integrate in this process