# Converting Custom (local) .PRJ to .PROJ4

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, proj

I have a Local PRJ file that I want to use in QGIS but how do I convert it to PROJ4?

Details for the PRJ file as below (based of GDA94 / MGA Zone 53)

```
JMG
Authority: Custom

Projection: Rectified_Skew_Orthomorphic_Center
False_Easting: 54007.558
False_Northing: 79754.287
Scale_Factor: 1.0
Azimuth: 0.0
Longitude_Of_Center: 132.217585217
Latitude_Of_Center: -30.885645673
XY_Plane_Rotation: -1.430068
Linear Unit: Meter (1.0)

Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_GRS_1980
Angular Unit: Degree (0.0174532925199433)
Prime Meridian: Greenwich (0.0)
Datum: D_GRS_1980
  Spheroid: GRS_1980
    Semimajor Axis: 6378137.0
    Semiminor Axis: 6356752.314140356
    Inverse Flattening: 298.257222101
```

Comment: Maybe related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87213/wkt-for-local-mine-grid

Comment: I found something related using a GDAL tool (gdalsrsinfo utility) in the following link, not yet tried myself.   https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/97947/copy-prj-file-into-qgis-projection-folder