# Installing/defining custom projection Nepal Modified UTN in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, nepal

I need to install/define a custom projection Nepal MUTM in qgis 2.14. But I don't know how to do it? Where will I get the projection code to use during defining?

Comment: After you get the code for custom projection, use below link to enter custom projection using this link http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20566/how-to-define-new-custom-projections-in-qgis

Answer (score 1):

It is defined at the Spatial Reference site, [here](http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/8024/). The Proj string is given as:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=84 +k=0.9999 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +a=6377276.345 +b=6356075.41314024 +units=m +no_defs
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. I searched the code some time ago and tried it but it didn't help.. Maybe am making some mistake.. I don't get the save button in the custom CRS definition window.. i am using qgis 2.14.0 Essen.. and I am also not sure if we should write something on the TEST portion of the window? Thank you!

Comment: It is confusing. After giving the CRS a name and entering the Proj string press the 'plus' (+) button again.

Comment: I did it.. the problem is that the new projection doesn't work :(

Comment: I had a quick look at this document http://azvoleff.com/content/2011-10-13-gis-and-gps-workshop/Day_3-Custom_Coordinate_Systems.pdf. From this it appears that 'Nepal Modified UTM' could in fact be any one of three projections (depending on which meridian the projection is aligned). Is it possible to post a link to a sample of your data?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a new profile in `Settings > User profiles > New profile`. Then the custom projection will work in any version of QGIS.

Comment: QGIS 2.x doesn't have `User profiles` in `Settings` menu. This answer is related to  QGIS 3.x.