# Import Cropland Data Layer

Tags: qgis, import

I am completely new to QGIS (and mapping in general), and I can't get my layers to line up.

> QGIS Version: 3.2.1-Bonn Standalone-installer Windows 10 64-bit

All of my layers are in the USA Contiguous Albers Equal Area projection. Currently, I have three layers:

- Site Coordinates
- World Imagery layer from ESRI
- Cropland Data Layer (CDL) from USDA-NASS CropScape

My coordinates line up perfectly with the *World Imagery* layer. However, the *CDL* is floating somewhere out in the universe and won't line up.

> CDL Extent:
>   48885.0000000000000000,2818725.0000000000000000 : 
>   117585.0000000000000000,2930685.0000000000000000

I downloaded the *CDL* as a zipped file containing a .tif and a .vat.dbf.tif file. 
I unzipped the file and uploaded it to QGIS as a .tif file.

Is it possible that the georeferencing for the .tif file is encoded in the .vat.dbf.tif file? How do I import the Cropland Data Layer to QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [FAQ for CropScape and Cropland Data Layers](https://www.nass.usda.gov/Research_and_Science/Cropland/sarsfaqs2.php#Section3_7.0):

> **What projections are used?**
>
> The CDL is processed using the Albers
> Equal-Area Conic USGS Projection
> (USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic_USGS_version) with a spheroid
> of GRS 1980 and datum of NAD83. The downloadable zip files from the
> SARS website and CropScape are offered in the native Albers
> projection.
>
> In order to conform to Geospatial Data Gateway technical
> specifications, any CDL data downloaded through the Geospatial Data
> Gateway is re-projected from Albers to the dominant Universal
> Transverse Mercator (UTM) zone with a spheroid and datum of WGS84. The
> one exception to the UTM projection is for Wisconsin. Wisconsin is
> projected using the Wisconsin Transverse Mercator (WTM) projection.
> This WTM projection is based on the 1991 adjustment to NAD83, and is
> called WTM83/91. Projection parameters and additional information
> about WTM83/91 is posted on the DNR website:
> http://dnr.wi.gov/maps/gis/wtm8391.html

**If you downloaded the CDL layer from the Geospatial Data Gateway**, it's in the "dominant" (I assume this means local) UTM zone with a spheroid and datum of WGS84.

**If you downloaded the CDL layer from the SARS website or CropScape**, it's in USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic_*USGS_version* (not USA Contiguous Albers Equal Area Conic). This seems to be a non-standard projection, because it doesn't have an EPSG code, and QGIS doesn't have it. You can [create a custom projection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/20566/81764), using the proj4 definition:

> +proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs

I found the proj4 definition on [github](https://gist.github.com/patchdynamics/2f11da7d9353edda3722), so no promises that it's correct. All credit goes to [patchdynamics](https://gist.github.com/patchdynamics).

It might be easier to download the layer from Geospatial Data Gateway instead.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have found a solution. CropScape claims to provide data in EPSG:102003, however on inspection the data is actually EPSG:5070.

QGIS 3 on windows read it as 102003 for some reason. Changing that in
the properties puts the file in the correct place. Hopefully this issue is resolved.