# Creating custom projection in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

How can I create a custom projection with the following parameters as per ArcGIS Desktop?

```
PROJCS["Lambert",GEOGCS["GCS_NZGD_2000",DATUM["D_NZGD_2000",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",175.0],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",-35.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

I need to create one in QGIS.

Comment: This question may help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20566/how-to-define-new-custom-projections-in-qgis

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple vector (i.e., points) layer with any CRS, digitize a feature and save it as a shapefile.

Then, in the folder where you saved the layer, will be (besides the *.shp* file) a *.qpj* and a *.prj* file.

- Remove the *.qpj* file.
- Edit the *.prj* file in a text editor, replacing its content with the Esri WKT provided.
- Load the layer in QGIS again.

QGIS will not find the *.qpj* file and will create a custom CRS for the layer, with the parameters of the *.prj* file:

`+proj=laea +lat_0=-35 +lon_0=175 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs`

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked...the issue I have now is that I have the projected layer fine in qgis. Then I bring in a layer with lat/lol coordinates and using qgis 3.4 I believe is should be projected on the fly. But the layers do not align although they should. Any ideas how to solve this? Many thanks again as I am new to QGIS and have a lot to learn!

Comment: Most welcome. The answer is a method to create a custom CRS from an Esri WKT. Your new problem is very common when you start working with projections, there is an innumerable amount of posts about it. The best way to helping you (in solving and understanding your specific issue) is through a new question with the data (project and layers files) attached to it.

Comment: What I can imagine, is that you have defined the custom CRS to a layer instead of [projecting](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/reproject_transform.html#moderate-fa-saving-a-dataset-to-another-crs) it to it.

Comment: Thank you very much once again for getting back to me. I actually spend some time trying to understand projections and I think I understood it (as I managed to align the two layers). So first I bring the two layers in lat/lon..then I reproject them to the desired projection schema and save them with this projection and then I can add them again with this projection into a new project displaying now in my desired projection. This seemed to work and actually I wanted to add the geometry and have the x/y in meters which also worked. thanks again for all the help!